# personalty quiz- radio type and value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make personalty quiz in HTML with javascript(no jquery)and I don't know where is my problem.

1. I know I need to put return false but I don't know were
2. I don't know how to use value well

```js
function count() {
  var first = document.querySelector('input[name=first]').value;
  var second = document.querySelector('input[name=second]').value;
  var dps = 0;
  var tank = 0;
  var sup = 0;
  if (first == 'dps') {
    dps++;
  }
  if (first == 'tank') {
    tank++;
  }
  if (first == 'sup') {
    sup++;
  }
  if (second == 'dps') {
    dps++;
  }
  if (second == 'tank') {
    tank++;
  }
  if (second == 'sup') {
    sup++;
  }

  var count2;
  if (dps > tank && dps > sup) {
    count2 = "dps";
  }
  if (tank > dps && tank > sup) {
    count2 = "tank";
  }
  if (sup > dps && sup > tank) {
    count2 = "sup";
  }

  var result = document.getElementById("motek");
  result.innerText = count2;
}
```

```html
<form id='hello' onsubmit="count()">
  <h3>what your favorite food?</h3>
  <input type="radio" name="first" value="tank">hghjghj<br>
  <input type="radio" name="first" value="dps">hghjfgsfghj<br>
  <input type="radio" name="first" value="sup">hghsgdsdqqwj<br>

  <h3>what your favoritsfde food?</h3>
  <input type="radio" name="second" value="tank">hghfsghj<br>
  <input type="radio" name="second" value="dps">hghesfghj<br>
  <input type="radio" name="second" value="sup">hghsfdqwj<br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<div id="motek">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop the page from reloading.

One great way to prevent reloading the page when submitting using a form is by adding `return false` with your `onsubmit` attribute.

In pure Javascript, you can also use: `e.preventDefault()`

OR you can make your `<button type="button">Submit</button>` type as button and handle form submit manually on click of this button.

The snippet below shows `return false` approach.

```js
function count() {
  var first = document.querySelector('input[name="first"]:checked').value;
  var second = document.querySelector('input[name="second"]:checked').value;
  
  var dps = 0;
  var tank = 0;
  var sup = 0;
  if (first == 'dps') {
    dps++;
  }
  if (first == 'tank') {
    tank++;
  }
  
  if (first == 'sup') {
    sup++;
  }
  
  if (second == 'dps') {
    dps++;
  }
  if (second == 'tank') {
    tank++;
  }
  
  if (second == 'sup') {
    sup++;
  }

  var count2;
  if (dps > tank && dps > sup) {
    count2 = "dps";
  } 
  
  if (tank > dps && tank > sup) {
    count2 = "tank";
  }
  
  if (sup > dps && sup > tank) {
    count2 = "sup";
  }

  var result = document.getElementById("motek");
  result.innerText = count2;
}
```

```html
<form id='hello' onsubmit="count(); return false">
  <h3>what your favorite food?</h3>
  <input type="radio" name="first" value="tank">hghjghj<br>
  <input type="radio" name="first" value="dps">hghjfgsfghj<br>
  <input type="radio" name="first" value="sup">hghsgdsdqqwj<br>

  <h3>what your favorite food?</h3>
  <input type="radio" name="second" value="tank">Tank<br>
  <input type="radio" name="second" value="dps">DPS<br>
  <input type="radio" name="second" value="sup">SUPP<br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<div id="motek">
</div>
```

Comment: first of all, thank u very much it's helped' but still my quiz don't work' the result is always 'tank' u know why?

Comment: It must be beacuse of of the If else condition that you have for tank ++ and others. Try checking why tank is printed

Comment: well it's not about the tank if I replace tank's lines with DPS line's DPS will be printed

Comment: Updated my snippet, you should see different result based on your selection

Comment: if it helped, Please accept and upvote if you can. Thanks